# Magit function to push

Tags: init-file, magit, configuration-files

Specially when editing my init.org file, I usually want to push every single change to origin. So I want to write a function to do this, I am almost there but still need some help.

```
(defun cesco/automatic-push ()
    (magit-stage-modified)
    (magit-commit (concat "-m \"" COMMIT MESSAGE "\""  ))
    (magit-push MAGIT-CURRENT-BRANCH)
)
```

I want the commit message to be the current day/time and push the current branch to origin.

## Update

I can successfully commit, but magit-push is running too fast so there is nothing commited yet. How can I make it wait for the commit to be done before attempting to push?

```
(defun cesco/push ()
    (interactive)
    (magit-stage-modified)
    (magit-commit (concat "-m \"" (format-time-string "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")  "\""))
    (magit-push)
  )
```

## Update 2

Code

```
(defun cesco/automatic-push ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-run-git "commit" "--all"
         (format-time-string "--message=%F %R"))
  (let ((current-branch (magit-get-current-branch)))
    (message "PUSHING!!!!")
    (magit-git-push current-branch
                    (concat "origin/" current-branch)
                    (list "--dry-run")
           )
    ))
```

1 try

```
  0 git … commit --all --message\=2017-05-08\ 01\:10
[master 03f269c8b701] 2017-05-08 01:10
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)

  0 git … push -v --dry-run origin master\:refs/heads/master
Pushing to git@github.com:cescoferraro/dotfiles.git
To git@github.com:cescoferraro/dotfiles.git
   798f05653e9e..03f269c8b701  master -> master
```

Removing (list "--dry-run")

```
  0 git … commit --all --message\=2017-05-08\ 01\:11
```

Comment: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InsertingTodaysDate here are some ways you can insert the date. I don't know about your other question.

Comment: @wvxvw thanks! Got the commit thing working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that I think fits your description.

```
(defun cesco/automatic-push ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-run-git "commit" "--all"
                 (format-time-string "--message=%F %R"))
  (let ((current-branch (magit-get-current-branch)))
    (magit-git-push current-branch
                    (concat "origin/" current-branch)
                    (list "--dry-run"))))
```

I've removed the `magit-stage-modified` because you can do this with
the `--all` flag to `git commit`.  (Note that the push call has a
"--dry-run" flag in there for testing.To actually push replace `(list "--dry-run")` with `nil`)

Instead of always pushing to origin, I'd recommend that you set the
upstream branch for your local branch and then push there.

Comment: i have removed the (list "--dry-run")  but still no push.

Comment: What does the magit process buffer show (`$`)?

Comment: i can see the pushing happen with the dry-run flag, otherwise it does not happen. I will update my question with the output

Comment: Are you still using your commit code?  Note that my commit call is different than yours, which is starting an editor to make the commit.

Comment: I think I made myself clearer now

Comment: I'm still confused.  I guess the process output that you removed in the edit was how it changed when you stopped using your commit code, but I don't know because you didn't say whether you were indeed mixing the code.  Anyway, are you getting an error now?  I'd guess that you're calling magit-git-push with the wrong number of arguments because you're removing (list "--dry-run") rather than replacing it with nil.